# file name matching does not group

Tags: python, regex

```
import zipfile
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
import re
from glob import glob


filenames = glob("/batch3/*C*_paired_fastqc.zip")


pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Z0-9-_]+)_L\d{3}\.*")
grouped = defaultdict(list)

for filename in filenames:
    match = pattern.search(filename)
    if match:
        key = match.group(1)
        grouped[key].append(filename)

pprint(grouped)

for i, g in enumerate(sorted(grouped.keys())):
    for f in grouped[g]:
        print f

    print "--------"
```

output:

```
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L003_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L001_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L002_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L003_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L004_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L001_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L002_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L004_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
--------
/batch3/0047-CLI_S8_L002_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0047-CLI_S8_L004_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0047-CLI_S8_L002_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0047-CLI_S8_L003_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0047-CLI_S8_L004_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0047-CLI_S8_L001_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0047-CLI_S8_L003_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0047-CLI_S8_L001_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
```

However, I would like to have:

```
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L001_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L001_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
---------
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L002_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L002_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
---------
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L003_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L003_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
--------- 
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L004_R1_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
/batch3/0046-CL7_S7_L004_R2_001_output_paired_fastqc.zip
```

Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to match the file names.

Comment: Your desired output does not appear to correspond with your inputs. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Your output isn't right... it has multiple identical file names. It seems like you are grouping on S7, S8 etc... when you want L001, L002, etc. So the regex is selecting the wrong part. try `"_L\d{3}_"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes:

- `re.compile(r"([A-Z0-9-_]+)_L\d{3}\.*")` ->
  `re.compile(r"([A-Z0-9-_]+)_L(\d{3})\.*")`
- `match.group(1)` ->
  `match.group()`

Your regex pattern was matching only the `0046`/`0047` part. The new one you make two groups, with second one matching the `L001`/ `L002` part. Some example of the `.group()` method behavior with this new pattern:

```
pattern.search(filenames[0]).group()
'0046-CL7_S7_L003'
pattern.search(filenames[0]).group(1)
'0046-CL7_S7'
pattern.search(filenames[0]).group(2)
'003'
```

Comment: It did work here using the 16 file names in your example. Make sure you have have made the two changes above. The other answer by Robᵩ is pretty much the same as mine and should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

1) Add parens `()` around your intended sorting key, like so:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(([A-Z0-9-_]+)_L\d{3})")
```

Note the additional parentheses.

Now `match.groups()` looks like: `('0046-CL7_S7_L003', '0046-CL7_S7')`, and you can use `match.group(1)` to sort.

2) Keep your regex the same, but use `match.group(0)` for your sorting:

```
    key = match.group(0)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? It worked fine in my test.